# Xcode UITableView Selection doesn't work when resized

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, selection

I've a problem with UITableView Row Selection, 
On View load (according to configuration) I resize TableView by 50px in that case click and selection doesn't work in these 50 pixel.

```
if (Config.alza){
    //Se non ho nessuno sconto incremento la dimensione della lista di 50Px necessari per mostrare gli sconti testata
    CGRect frame = ListaOrdine.frame;
    frame.size.height += 50;
    ListaOrdine.frame = frame;
}

//Attivo la gestione del click
TapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Click:)];
[TapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1]; 
[TapGesture setCancelsTouchesInView:NO]; //Serve per non bruciare l'evento click
[ListaOrdine addGestureRecognizer:TapGesture];
```

Someone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the height of a row using the table view delegate

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //Your existing code
    if (Config.alza){
        //Se non ho nessuno sconto incremento la dimensione della lista di 50Px necessari per mostrare gli sconti testata
        return yourDefaultCellHeight + 50;
    }

    return yourDefaultCellHeight;

}
```

Comment: I must not raise the height of the row. I want to use the whole screen (because i'll hide other control unnecessary)

Answer (score 0):

Implement this method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: I've implemented didselectrowatindexpath but event doesn't fire on that 50px

Comment: did you implement - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method ??

Comment: I have doubt that if you set delegate with xib.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by bringtofront tableview control after resize

```
if (Config.alza){
    //Se non ho nessuno sconto incremento la dimensione della lista di 50Px necessari per mostrare gli sconti testata
    CGRect frame = ListaOrdine.frame;
    frame.size.height += 50;
    ListaOrdine.frame = frame;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:ListaOrdine];
}
```

problem seems to be that newer 50px of tableview was covered by another view that fires the event instead of tableview